# How to bind Aggregate a list to Object rather than array in a JSON model?

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have the follwoing JSON model.

```
 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
"people": {
    "a": {
        "name": "csr",
        "number": 1
    },
    "b": {
        "name": "abc",
        "number": 2
    }
}
});
```

and I want oModel to get binded to  sap.m.List .

ex:

```
    new sap.m.List("asd")
   .placeAt('content')
   .setModel(oModel)
   .bindItems("/people", blah blah ...)
```

Problem: I see I can only bind arrays, i.e if people is array, List is getting binded fine...,but how to bind an object and loop through object ?????

Comment: I dont know much about sap but cant you convert json model to array?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't.

There's no way you can bind an object-of-objects and expect it to behave like a list-of-objects.

You could, however, create a new JSONModel which represents your object as if it were a list, but you will need to do the conversion yourself...

However, if I were you, I would just save me the hassle and rework your JSON model to represent what it should be: an array of objects.